# ObjectiveC random digits

Tags: objective-c, random

I need some help.
I want to generate numbers.But my numbers repeated.
how can I make the numbers don't repeat?
My code below.
Thanks

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Evaluation.h"
#define MAXDIGITCARDS 51
#define MINDIGITCARDS 0
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int userDigit=30;
        NSMutableArray* currentArray=[NSMutableArray new];  
        for (int a=0;a<userDigit;a++)
        {
            Evaluation *evaluation = [Evaluation new];
            int correctNumber = ((arc4random() % (MAXDIGITCARDS - MINDIGITCARDS)) + MINDIGITCARDS);
            [evaluation setCorrectNumber:correctNumber];
            [currentArray addObject:evaluation];
            [evaluation release];

        }
        [currentArray release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the setCorrectNumber function? or is it synthesized?

Comment: What is 'arc4random'? Why aren't you using random() from the standard C library?

Comment: CorrectNumber synthesized. In this class one variable int CorrectNumber

Comment: I study Objective C and try to make with arc4random

Comment: @jv42 arc4random() is generally acknowledged as a better (as in, "statistically-speaking more randomly random") generator than random() and srandom().

Comment: @Anton the "new" class method in Objective-C is deprecated if I'm not mistaken, and in general it is not recommended to use it.

Comment: Well generating 'statistically-speaking' good random numbers is useless if using a modulo on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'not repeat' you mean you want all 30 numbers to be different from each other, then each time you generate a number see if it already exists in `currentArray`. If it does, generate another one. Repeat until you get one that you haven't had already.

Alternatively (since it looks like you are shuffling cards) look at something like the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

Have you seeded the random number generator? Something like:

```
srandom(time(NULL));
```